# Scanned handwritten letters and other images - cross-referencing with transcriptions

Tags: cross-referencing

I have dozens of handwritten letters between family members, friends and colleagues from 1900 to 1920, with associated documents and images. I'm in the process of scanning everything, and plan to transcribe the scanned letters into text files, and provide additional explanatory information and cross-referencing, e.g. to explain a nickname using a link to a biographical file on that individual, or to link photographic images to locations and the individuals portrayed in them.
Is there a TeX-LaTeX package that would give me a head-start on this? Or some worked examples to help me avoid time-consuming trips down blind alleys?

Comment: Welcome. Your question is very broad. What tasks do you need exactly? Referencing images and texts is built in (label/ref). In your description, that is all you need, i guess. Maybe a glossary, https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries but other than that... i don't see much more you need. Maybe have a look at this: http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/memoir/memman.pdf

Comment: Thanks, Sango. These are obviously approaches I need to study.